# How to upload Pdf, Docs, txt, Images in Firebase Storage using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I'm trying creating a iOS app where the user can upload pdf, images, docs etc...,

This is my code - it works just one time; when I try again I get the error shown down below.

I don't understand why - I'm new to iOS development

```
class DocumentViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate{
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    
    enum UploadFileType{
        case file
        case PDF
    }
    struct UploadFileData{
        var fileName: String
        var fileType: UploadFileType
        var fileData: NSData
    }
    
    var file: UploadFileData?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func addDocumetPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let documentsPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypeImage), String(kUTTypeVideo), String(kUTTypePlainText),String(kUTTypeItem),String(kUTTypeFolder)], in: .import)
        documentsPicker.delegate = self
        documentsPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        present(documentsPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        
        let files = storage.reference().child("Customer Name")
        
        files.child((urls.first?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent)!).putFile(from: urls.first!,metadata: nil){
            (_, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Files didn't upload, \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            print("Success")
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> Files didn't upload, Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=40, *NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask .<1>, bucket=rgtestiosapp.appspot.com, object=customer Name/Boundaries* When to Say Yes, How to Say No to Take Control of Your Life ( PDFDrive ), _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "BackgroundUploadTask .<1>",
> "LocalUploadTask .<1>"
> ), NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 28, bytes = 0x1c1e01bb 00000000 2a001450 4001082b ... 0000200a 00000000 }, ResponseErrorCode=40})

Comment: Can you try removing deletingPathExtension?

Comment: I try it but no success, thanks anyway

Comment: It's the second day that I have been working to solve this problem, What I have found is I try the same project in another pc in Virtualmachine and it wokrs, but in my mac with M1 chip it's not working because my app doesn't show up in the privacy of the folder Settings>Privacy>File and Folder

Comment: There could be a number of issues causing that error. You're force unwrapping a lot of vars which could lead to crashes. Also, there's no troubleshooting indicated it the question... did you add a breakpoint and step through your code line by line, inspecting vars and code execution along the way until you spot something unexpected? Can you do that and tell us which line is providing unexpected results and what you were expecting?

Comment: I put a breakpoint and i follow each step when the breakpoint was at putFile he throw the error files.child((urls.first?.lastPathComponent)!).putFile(from: urls[0].absoluteURL,metadata: nil)

Comment: Great first step! Now you need to determine what this `urls.first?.lastPathComponent` resolves to as `first` is an optional and could be nil and you're force unwrapping everything within the parens `()!` which could be crashing as well. And while you're at it, what does this `urls[0].absoluteURL` resolve to?

Comment: This urls.first?.lastPathComponent take only the name and the type of the document that I select to upload.  Like this work just one time i need to turn off and turn on the simulator to make this work.